# Openshift: how to edit scc non-interactively?

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin

I am experimenting with openshift/minishift, I find myself having to run:

`oc edit scc privileged`

and add:

`- system:serviceaccount:default:router`

So I can expose the pods. Is there a way to do it in a script?

I know  `oc adm` have some command for policy manipulation but I can't figure out how to add this line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve it using `oc patch` command and with type json. The snippet below will add a new item to array before 0th element. You can try it out with a fake "bla" value etc.

```
oc patch scc privileged --type=json -p '[{"op": "add", "path": "/users/0", "value":"system:serviceaccount:default:router"}]'
```

The `--type=json` will interpret the provided patch as [jsonpatch](http://jsonpatch.com/) operation. Unfortunately `oc patch --help` doesn't provide any example for json patch type. Luckily example usage can be found in kubernetes docs: [kubectl patch](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#patch)

Comment: Awesome! I coud not find `oc patch` +1,   `oc replace -f -`  did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have found an example piping to `sed` [Here](https://blog.openshift.com/setting-openshift-3-openstack/) and adapted it to ruby so I can easily edit the data structure.

```
oc get scc privileged -o json |\ 
ruby -rjson -e 'i = JSON.load(STDIN.read); i["users"].push "system:serviceaccount:default:router"; puts i.to_json ' |\
oc replace scc -f -
```

Here is  [quick and dirty script](https://gist.github.com/tlopo/f584616478118a7a27b30a254198a124) to get started with minishift

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to add and remove users to SCCs from the command line is using the `oc adm policy` commands:

```
oc adm policy add-scc-to-user <scc_name> <user_name>
```

For more info, see [this section](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.7/admin_guide/manage_scc.html#grant-access-to-the-privileged-scc).

---

So for your specific use-case, it would be:

```
oc adm policy add-scc-to-user privileged system:serviceaccount:default:router
```

I'm surprised its needed though. I use "oc cluster up" normally, but testing with recent minishift, its already added out of the box:

```
$ minishift start
$ eval $(minishift oc-env)
$ oc login -u system:admin
$ oc get scc privileged -o yaml | grep system:serviceaccount:default:router
- system:serviceaccount:default:router

$ minishift version
minishift v1.14.0+1ec5877
$ oc version
openshift v3.7.1+a8deba5-34
```