# Replace a parameter in openshift scc restricted yaml

Tags: yaml, openshift, json-patch

Currently in my openshift environment, I have to manually go and edit my scc restricted yaml file using the command `oc edit scc restricted`.
In this file I am updating two parameters: 
`allowHostDirVolumePlugin: false` **TO** `allowHostDirVolumePlugin: true` 
**AND** 
`runAsUser:
  type: MustRunAsRange` **TO** 
`runAsUser:
  type: RunAsAny`

I want to be able to update these values without actually editing them. I have tried the json patch method mentioned [**HERE**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42310262/openshift-how-to-edit-scc-non-interactively) but in that example, I am able to add. I am trying the same using something like 
`oc patch scc restricted --type=json -p '[{"op": "replace", "path": "/allowHostDirVolumePlugin", "value":"true"}]'` but it keeps giving an error `Error from server: [pos 29]: json: decode bool: got first char "`

Is there any way to achieve this without editing the yml file?

Comment: What happens if instead of ``"true"`` you use ``true``,  no quotes. It is expecting a boolean, not a string.

Comment: Thanks @GrahamDumpleton this worked like a charm! This was just a silly error on my part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Graham has alluded to in his comment, you are trying to set a boolean value as a string. You should be able to update both values with one line, try:

`oc patch scc restricted --patch='{"allowHostDirVolumePlugin": true, "runAsUser":{"type":"RunAsAny"}}'`